# To calculate average by taking command line argument

Tags: bash, shell

The task is that if input numbers:

```
4
1
2
9
8
```

Output=(sum of all except first_number_in_series)/first_number in series
Then output average should be `1+2+9+8/(first_number_in series)=20/4=5`

I have tried the following code, however not able to achieve the task. I will be grateful if anyone can point out the mistake.

```
#!/bin/bash
sum=0
count=1
for x in $*
do
    if [ $count -eq 1 ]
    then
        p=$x
    else
        sum=$(($sum + $x))
    fi
    ((count++))
done
echo "scale=3;$sum/$p" | bc
```

Comment: What's wrong with your code?

Comment: not giving the desired output...pls check

Comment: For me, it looks like you include first number in your average, and it's the main problem. I'm going to check if I'm right.

Comment: I think the problem may be elsewhere; your script does what you want, but maybe you're calling it differently? It's expecting the numbers to be passed to it while your answer below specifically reads from stdin and ignores any numbers passed to it. Show us the error you're getting.

Comment: Feels like it would be easier to `shift` p off before starting to do the sum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You failed to say that the numbers are given to the script in the stdin.

For that, this code will work:

```
#!/bin/bash
readarray -t x
count="${x[0]}" ; unset x[0]
for y in ${x[@]}; do (( sum+=y )); done
a="$(echo "scale=8; $sum/$count" | bc)"
LC_ALL=C printf '%0.3f\n' "$a"
```

Test it as this:

```
$ printf '%s\n' 4 1 2 9 8 | ./script
5.000
$ printf '%s\n' 6 1 2 9 8 13 25 | ./script
9.667
```

Comment: What is the difference between stdin and normal inputs?? I am new to bash, it will be greatful if u can clearify this for me...thnx

Comment: Also, in the above code if the output is 9.6666, then answer is expected to be 9.667,then how to achieve this task in ur testcase 2 wherein the answer is 9.6666 how to display rounded off value such as 9.667?

Comment: The difference is like the difference between this two lines: `./script 1 2 3 4` and `echo 1 2 3 4 | ./script`. The first supply the arguments in the array of "positional arguments" (similar to c ARGV[]), the second supply the values in the stdin input (no ARGV is set).

Comment: Rounding is a very slippery slope. You can get what you ask for with printf: `LC_ALL=C; a=9.666666; printf '%0.3f' "$a"` (output 9.667), but even that is bound to fail in some other corner cases.

Comment: In which cases will it result into failure??? and in our code, where shall i include printf  '%0.3f'??

Comment: [Read this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/240112/weird-float-rounding-behavior-with-printf) (as one example) and code edited in the answer. Something else still?

Comment: thnx dear....for further any queries will surely discuss with u...thnx a lot...wish u a vry happy and prosperous future ahead!!!
also for sed and awk utilities pls guide me any good material or reference from which i can prepare them...thnx once again

Answer (score 2):

Since you need floating point calculation, you will end up using bc, or awk, anyways. Why not use Awk to solve the whole problem? Here is a Awk only solution, I used n for numerator and d for denominator:

```
$ printf "4\n1\n2\n9\n8\n" | awk '{if (NR == 1) {d = $0}; if (NR != 1) {n += $0}} END{printf "%.03f\n", n/(d*1.0)}'
5.000
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple POSIX solution:

```
average() { printf '%s\n' 'scale=2' "($*)/$#" | tr ' ' + | bc;}
```

Then run it like so:

```
average 4 1 2 9 8
```

Output: `4.80`

Answer (score 0):

You were including the first number in the sum and you wrote a bad condition:

`if [ count -eq "1" ]`

instead of

`if [ $count -eq 1 ]`

`$` operator let you access to a variable and you were using 1 as a String instead of a integer.

```
#!/bin/bash
read n
p=$n
sum=0
count=1
while [ $count -le $p ]
do
    read n
    x=$n
    count=$(($count + 1))
    sum=$(($sum + $x))
done
result=`echo $sum $p | awk '{printf "%.3f", $1/$2 }'`
echo $result
```

Comment: sir output with this code is syntax error in standard input

Comment: Compiler Message
Wrong Answer
Error (stderr)
(standard_in) 2: syntax error

Comment: I'm executing it in my shell right now, it's working... I just added an else branch..

Comment: pls check the same code by putting on the challenge page https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/bash-tutorials---compute-the-average

it gives the error

@GingerPlusPlus u also check sir

Comment: The problem is with the hackerank interpreter... something happens with bc...

Comment: I'm doing it with awk right now but hackerrank can't do it... i don't know why, but it's working on my computer...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35415/discussion-between-edugr-and-farhan-patel).

Comment: It's done... it's working on hackerrank i got the challenge :)

Comment: using which solution its working in hackerrank interpreter???@EduGR

Comment: The solution of my comment...i updated it and i got the challenge in Hackerrank

Comment: yes gud it is amazing....thnx for the concept....